# Error using interop.Shdocvw

Tags: c#, interop, watin, shdocvw

I was trying to connect to web browser control but it continuously threw exception that iwebbrowser2 should implement iwebbrowser2  something like this ,then i googled and found solution to this ,chose com objects then from there microsoft web browser after chosing i got control to apply on form and i did.

next wrote code

```
var t = new Thread(() =>
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    
    //new FormDialogWatcher(frm1.Handle);
    Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher = false;
    var ie = new IE( frm1.WebBrowser1);
    
    ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");
});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

as other threads at stack overflow suggest.added reference introp.SHdocve but when i build 68 errors occured:

> Error  64
>
> Cannot embed interop type 'SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE' found in both assembly 'e:\XMLreader\lib\Interop.SHDocVw.dll' and 'e:\XMLreader\XMLreader\obj\x86\Debug\Interop.SHDocVw.dll'. onsider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false.

I right clicked at this dll and changed embed interop to false but with no effect.

I commented out `var ie = new IE( frm1.WebBrowser1);`and all 68 errors were gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want the Form at all.  Try this:

```
var ie = new IE();
```

The ApartmentState can be set for the whole application within the config as well.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>


</configuration>
```